# JUnit testing: Improvement to test case, testing for length of array List?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

Below is the method that I wish to test, it is basically a method that allows the user to search for a book in a library system using an ISBN number:

```
/**
     * Search by ISBN
     * @param ISBN
     * @return ArrayList of found books matching search criteria
     */
    public ArrayList<Book> searchByISBN(String ISBN) {
        ArrayList<Book> results = new ArrayList<Book>();

        for (int loop = 0; loop < allBooks.size(); loop++) {
            if (allBooks.get(loop).getISBN().equals(ISBN)) {
                // add book to search
                results.add(allBooks.get(loop));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Below is the JUnit test case that I have written for this method:

```
@Test
    public void testSearchByISBN() {
        LibrarySearch ls = new LibrarySearch(arrayList);
        ArrayList<Book> results =  ls.searchByISBN(ISBNB2);

        if (results.contains(b2)){
            assertTrue(true);
        } else {
            assertTrue(false);
        }

    }
```

Is there any obv imporvements I could make to this test case, my lecturer mentioned testing the length of the array list but im unsure what functionality that would add?

Answer (score 1):

use assertj to verify the results. generate or write your own matchers. you can use giava to easily build lists. use factory methods to create books. and you may get something like:

```
public void should_return_list_of_books_with_matching_ISBN() {

  // given    
  List<Book> allBooks = Lists.newArrayList(
                                   bookWithISBN("1"), 
                                   bookWithISBN("1"),
                                   bookWithISBN("2"));
  // when
  List<Book> result = new LibrarySearch(allBooks).searchByISBN("1");

  //then
  assertThat(result)
                .each(hasISBN("1"))
                .hasSize(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build a list of expected results, for instance:

```
final List<Book> expected = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3);
```

where you know that `book1`, `book2` and `book3` obey the criterion.

Then build your `LibrarySearch` object and check that:

```
assertEquals(results, expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

First `assertTrue` expects a boolean and you can check the return value accordingly.

```
assertTrue(results.contains(b2));
```

With `assertEquals` you can test equality of two values.

```
assertEquals(3, results.size());
```

Additionally please take a look at fge's answer. You may have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions , too.